# Android cropper cannot go beyond 256?

Tags: android

I'm using the android cropper, and when I set the image size above 256, I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
> ```

```
intent.setData( _captureUri );
    intent.putExtra( "outputX", 512 );
intent.putExtra( "outputY", 512 );
intent.putExtra( "aspectX", 1 );
intent.putExtra( "aspectY", 1 );
intent.putExtra( "scale", true );
```

Does anyone know of another 3rd party image cropper?

**Update!!**
There is definitely a hardcoded value of 256, how does this affect my cropping?:

http://codesearch.google.com/#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/apps/Gallery3D/src/com/cooliris/media/CropImage.java&type=cs&l=624

Comment: did you try extending cropimage.java to make it valid for something greater than 256?

Comment: @hunterp did you solve this issue?

Comment: duplicate, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758425/how-to-set-the-output-image-use-com-android-camera-action-crop/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cropper is part of the Gallery3D app, it's not a public APK. It may or may not be available, and it may break/change at any time. Copy the relevant classes to your project and modify them to suit your needs.

As for the error, the maximum size of data you can transfer with intents is around 1Mb, if you go over this you will get an error. Look at the source, I think it has an option to save the crop result to a Uri, that should get rid of the binder error.

Comment: thanks for the information and where can i get those classes?

Comment: Get the Android source code from AOSP and check the gallery and/or camera apps.

Comment: any idea how to handle for the >1mb binder exception?

Comment: Save to file and pass the uri, see above.